# How to split a string of characters/alphabets without space/separator into dictionary words?

Tags: python, r, text, nlp

I have a string that consists of two or more dictionary English words, but the spaces between the words is missing. How can I separate the words in R or Python?

**Example:**

```
Input_string = "thequickbrownfox"

Desired_output_string = "the quick brown fox"
```

Is there an algorithm to do such text processing?

Comment: Good luck. I believe this is off-topic for SO, but you might have better luck asking about methodologies (not *packages*) that could address something like this ... and that question would be more appropriate at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) or (less likely) [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Fair enough, methodologies are welcome

Comment: Nothing will be perfect... for example, take the string `"ilovetherapists"`; would that be `"i love therapists"` or `"i love the rapists"`.

Comment: sure let it be. the more options the better. but more importanty we sud be able t split it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a linear problem.  Among other difficulties, some character sequences can be separated into more than one reasonable string of words.

However, the approach is straightforward with a recursive routine.  Go through your lexicon (dictionary of legal words) and find *each* word you can form from the start of the given sentence.  Iterate through those words; for each, parse the rest of the sentence.  If successful, return the properly separated input (current word + parsing of the remainder).

```
// Parse a character sequence
//   return a list of legal word separations
// Assume a word list, lexicon, as a global
sep_string(str sentence)
    result = <empty list>
    sent_size = length of sentence

    for word_size in 1:sent_size
        word = sentence[0:word_size-1]  // next potential word

        if word in lexicon
            // Found a legal word; remove it and parse
            //   the rest of the sequence
            sep_rest = sep_string(sentence[word_size:sent_size])
            // sep_rest is a list of parsings for
            //   the rest of the sequence

            for each solution in sep_rest
                append (word + " " + solution) to result

    return result
```